# How to do model selection in the unsupervised learning setting?

Tags: clustering, model-selection, unsupervised-learning

For supervised learning, we know the correct answers for samples, model selection is more easier, we can use k-ford cross validation (this site!) and etc.

But for unsupervised learning, e.g. clustering, how can we determine the optimal number of clusters?

I read some literature about Kullback-Leibler information criterion but its performance is not quite good after I tried some simulations.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Please find here a set of methods for model evaluation and selection for unsupervised learning (esp. K-means clustering) http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534/notes/Unsupervised-model-11.pdf